# inequality of the chi squared distribution function with d degree of freedom and the one with two

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, functions, inequality, probability-distributions

Good morning, I can't find how to prove this inequality :

$F_d(x) ≥ (⌊d/2⌋ + 1)*F_2(x/(⌊d/2⌋ + 1))$

where $F_d(x) = P(\lVert Z_s \rVert^2 \leq x)$ with $Z_s \sim\mathcal{N}(0, I_d)$

I have the intuition we should group together two by two the component of the vector but then I don't know how to show it.
I guess we have to use the fact that $F_d(x)$ is the distribution function of the $\chi^2(d)$ distribution.

Comment: As $x \to \infty$, we have $F_d(x) \to 1$.  So when $d \ge 2$ and for sufficiently large $x$, I don't see how your inequality could be true.  The LHS will be bounded above by $1$, yet the RHS is bounded above by $\lfloor d/2 \rfloor + 1$, unless I am misunderstanding your notation.